# How to restart httpuv server periodically

Tags: r

Using `httpuv` package, Is there a way to restart server with given period?

Down there, I'm sharing my work as a possible answer.

Any further advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, here's a working code that restarts server every 5 seconds:

```
library(httpuv)

host <- '127.0.0.1'

port <- 8080

app <- list(
  call = function(req) {
    list(
      status = 200L,
      headers = list('Content-Type' = 'text/plain'),
      body = 'Hello'
    )
  }
)

run <- function(host, port, app, period) {
  sv <- startServer(host, port, app)
  on.exit(stopServer(sv))
  cat("Server started\n")

  restart <- Sys.time() + period

  while (TRUE) {
    service()
    Sys.sleep(0.001)
    if (Sys.time() > restart) {
      stopServer(sv)
      sv <- startServer(host, port, app)
      restart <- Sys.time() + period
      cat("Server restarted\n")
    }
  }
}

run(host, port, app, 5)
```